# Docker Mariadb dump import not Working: mysql: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: mysql, database, docker, import, mariadb

I recently exported a dump file from my working MySQL database. I want to run it on a docker MariaDB database. Problem is, that the import is not working. It's throwing the following error message:

```
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string.
```

Do you have any idea what the issue could be? Thank you for your help in advance.

My dump file:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `trackmap` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE 
utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */;
USE `trackmap`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.27, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: trackmap
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.27

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `gruppe`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gruppe`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `gruppe` (
  `GroupID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Beschreibung` varchar(140) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GruppenFarbe` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `gruppe`
--

LOCK TABLES `gruppe` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `gruppe` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `gruppe` VALUES (1,'tolleGruppe','Eine tolle Gruppe','weiß'), 
(2,'superGruppe','Eine super Gruppe','rot');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `gruppe` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geolat` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `geolong` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('Jakob','Jakob',0,0), 
('Hendrick','Hendrick',49.99135204584314,8.280738733723956), 
('Zoe','Zoe',50.06812365779786,8.236003513207015), 
('Lenny','Lenny',51.21475408000626,6.779539564097885), 
('Maximilian','Maximilian',53.49847387955471,10.042672857321604);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `usergruppe`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usergruppe`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `usergruppe` (
  `GroupID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `usergruppe`
--

LOCK TABLES `usergruppe` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usergruppe` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `usergruppe` VALUES (1,'Jakob'),(1,'Zoe'),(1,'Maximilian'),(1,'Lenny'), 
(1,'Hendrick');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usergruppe` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2021-12-17 15:53:30
```

Comment: is it spitting the error for a specific line?

Comment: No unfortunately not, after the import finnished the error message gets generated in the cmd.

Comment: did you try deleting parts of it to see where it passes?

Comment: How are you trying to import this? (Because there seems to be nothing wrong with the SQL dump you shared...)

Comment: there is no utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci in MariaDB. replace it with something mariadb understands, utf8mb4_general_ci, utf8mb4_unicode_ci or something like tat